# Compile meta values from custom loop into array and then calculate sum total

Tags: wp-query, post-meta

I tried explaining this yesterday but I fear I made things more complicated than they needed to be.

I have a custom loop that pulls through standard Wordpress posts with various arguments.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 50,
    'post__in' => array(2, 3, 7, 53, 75)
);
```

These posts all have a custom meta field called `post_views` which, based on a custom function, counts the page views of that particular post.

What I need to be able to do is combine the values of all these meta values and calculate the sum total that I can output into my theme.

So, for example;

- If the 5 posts defined in the `post__in` argument each have 100 views, the sum total of all 5 `post_views` meta values would be 500.

I hope I have explained this a little better than my last attempt.

Any questions, please don't hesitate to ask.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This does make much more sense, and I think @birgire nailed it

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you mean this kind of loop:

```
$total_views = 0;
$post_ids    = [2, 3, 7, 53, 75];

foreach( $post_ids as $post_id )
{ 
    $total_views += (int) get_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_views', true );
}
```

to calculate the total sum.

Comment: That is how I read it as well.