# Calculate all custom field values in the post loop

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, loop

I have a custom post type named 'ordered_food' and the custom field named 'price',
Alhough I can print out all the values, I don't know how to plus and calculate the total price. Because it's already in the wordpress custom post type loop.

[image: Calculate all custom field values in the post loop]

```
/* something like this */
$total_amount = $price_custom_field1 + $price_custom_field2 + $price_custom_field3;
```

Comment: It helps to see the relevant code. There was a [similar question here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/209673/compile-meta-values-from-custom-loop-into-array-and-then-calculate-sum-total) asked recently that might help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//loop start

    $total_amount = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_field1', true);
    $total_amount += get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_field2', true);
    $total_amount += get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_field3', true);

//loop end  

    echo 'Total: '.$total_amount;
```